# Will a firmware update erase my personal data?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5

A friend of mine has a Samsung Galaxy S5.
It is actually prompting to update the firmware. But the updatetext (its actually in german) reads ambiguous. Translated it says something along the lines

> Initalize the latest Version.
>
> All configurations will be initialized and saved data will be erased.

The problem with the german text is it isn't distingtive this means just the Configurations data or ALL data. I wasn't able to find someone having this problem by googling (I'll just get spammed how to delete/erase the updateprompting...)

SO I'm asking here:

What kind of data is meant to be erased for a Samsung Galaxy S5 when performing the latest firmware update? (If it matters, current version: PDA:OJ1 / CSC:OJ1 / PHONE:OJ3(XEF))

Answer (score -1):

Do a backup of your phone's important files, don't risk it, if the phone reinitialises it isually resets it to its factory version, erasing all the data. Also your apps are very likely saved in a list so that you can reinstall them after the reset, so don't worry about them. Use google drlive or some other service, take the SD card out, and do the firmware update, if you want. Just don't risk it.

Comment: My question actually is, is the text actually saying it is going to DO erase my data? In that case I can't see where there is any risk if it is ensured. Otherwise: refer to that please.

Comment: "All configurations are going to be initialized and saved data will be erased." The way it is translated, if it's translated right, does say you'll lose the data. Usually settings are juat referred to  as "settings" or "configuration", and when the word data is mentioned it means the stocked data and files, not just configuration files; the alert distincts the two things. So yes it's saying it will delete your data as it appears here.

Comment: I know what it is saying, since I wrote it to express that one meaning could be it is doing so. But if my intention would have been to get to know what the exact meaning of that sentence was, I would have asked on EEL and not here. What I'm asking is if the firmwareupdate of a samsung galaxy s5 device is intended to erase personal data by any means.(Since the german text COULD be intepreted that way) But what I'm not asking is: What the text I translated from german into english could mean in german.....

Comment: @Zaibis: firmware update is *NOT intended to erase personal data*

Comment: Exactly, but I think he ought not to risk it. By the translation he gave it seems that this will wipe his data away, unusual as it may be, I think it's always better to backup